# How do you properly make a backdoor shell with netcat using UDP?

Tags: network

See the reference image below. When issuing commands to a bash shell via a netcat connecting using UDP only the first character of the command seems to make it to the server. Moreover, after entering the command a second newline is required.

Why does this behavior occur? What is the proper way to create a shell using netcat+udp?

[image: Example of broken UDP behavior]

I'm using GNU Netcat 0.7.1 by Giovanni Giacobbi

Comment: What version of Linux are you using for this? Netcat is a bit different across the various distributions and can effect the behavior of some flags.

Comment: Trying the flags you are using with /bin/nc.traditional under Ubuntu I get nothing when using the UDP flag not the single character issue you are seeing. But works fine with TCP.

Answer (score 1):

Have a quick look at a related netcat query on serverfault [here](https://serverfault.com/q/128956/62544) - this may help. UDP does not behave as well as TCP.

Answer (score 0):

"iodine lets you tunnel IPv4 data through a DNS server. This can be usable in different situations where internet access is firewalled, but DNS queries are allowed."

http://code.kryo.se/iodine/

Comment: Thanks for the info. iodine looks like an interesting tool. However in this case I want to know the technical reason for netcat's strange behavior, I'm not looking for alternatives.